# Как я могу запретить 2D объекту изменять свой Scale?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Дело в том , что иногда в игре происходят "баги" и 2D спрайт(персонаж) изменяет свой размер.
Как я могу запретить 2D объекту изменять свой Scale?

Comment: при каждом update устанавливайте туда 1

Comment: Самопроизвольно Scale измениться не может. Поэтому вместо "костыля" на запрет изменения Scale лучше найти причину - или какой-то код или аниматор меняет масштаб Вашего спрайта.